# Properly threading and piping data between main window and thread in PyQt5

Tags: multithreading, pyqt5

I am trying to wrap my head around threading (specifically using PyQT5 QThread).

I have an application that gets used to scan invitations at the entrance of events. People show up, show their invitation, scan the QR code and get their badge printed out.
It works as it is.

However, I want to add synchronisation between different scanning posts, using the Reticulum network stack. Because I can't have the main program wait while connections are being set up, I'd use Threading. Communicating between the Thread and the main window is where I'm not sure how things should be done.
I read that I shouldn't call methods from the thread directly, but the books I've read all seem to craft their examples so that there is limited interaction between the thread and the main window.

Imagine my class to handle the communication is like this:

```py
class LinkClient(QObject):



    def __init__(self, rns_config_file: Union[str, None] = None):
        RNS.Reticulum(rns_config_file)
        self.packet_received = pyqtSignal(str)

    def connect_to_server(self, server_hash: str, timeout_s: float = 10):
        ### all the code to connect to the server goes here
        self._setup_link()  # set up the link INCLUDING CALLBACKS
        log.debug(f'Connection to {server_hash} complete')

    def _setup_link(self) -> None:
        self._link = RNS.Link(self._server_dest)
        self._link.set_packet_callback(self._packet_callback)
        self._link.set_link_established_callback(self._link_established_callback)

    def disconnect(self) -> None:
        self._link_established.teardown()

    def _link_established_callback(self, link: RNS.Link) -> None:
        self._link_established = link

    def _link_closed_callback(self, link: RNS.Link):
        # should signal to main window. How?
    
    def _packet_callback(self, msg, packet) -> None:
        # --> How do I signal this to the main window?
        self.packet_received.emit(msg) # Like this?

    @pyqtSlot(str)   # I think this should become a slot
    def send_message(self, text: str) -> None:
        data = text.encode('utf-8')
        RNS.Packet(self._link_established, data=data).send()
```

The important parts of the code in the MainWindow:

```py
    def _set_up_datalink(self) -> None:
        # Sets up the datalink class in a separate thread
        self.datalink_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.datalink = LinkClient()
        datalink.moveToThread(self.datalink_thread)
        self.datalink_thread.start()
        # The following apparently should not be done (calling methods directly)
        self.datalink.connect_to_server(self.config.datalink_server_hash)
        # connect incoming data to the handler in the main window
        self.datalink.packet_received.connect(self.send_data)  # Like this?

    def send_data(self,data:str) -> None:
        # I shouldn't call the method from the Threaded class, right?
        self.datalink.send_message(text=data)    

    def handle_incoming_data(self,str):
        log.debug(f'Received {str}')
```

What is the proper way to handle this? The examples I find in books seem to avoid the functionality I want. Maybe I want things that shouldn't be done?

Comment: It seems like you're asking suggestions on how to implement Qt threading, but this is not really the scope of StackOverflow. I'm not familiar with that module, so I cannot tell you much more on that aspect, but I can clearly spot at least two important issues in your code: 1. you never called the `super().__init__(); 2. signals are declared at class level, not in instance methods. That said, don't ask if something is correct: try to do it and see if it works. Start with simple tests just to begin to understand the basics, then move on to the full implementation.

Comment: Also: don't call `connect_to_server` directly. Pass `server_hash` and `timeout` as arguments to `LinkClient.__init__` and store them as attributes so they can be accessed by the other methods internally later. Then do `self.datalink_thread.started.connect(self.datalink.connect_to_server)`. All signal connections should be made *before* starting the thread. And all communication between the link-client and main thread should be done using custom signals and slots (in both directions). Qt automatically detects cross-thread signals and delivers them asynchronously (via the event-queue).

Comment: @ekhumoro Ok, that makes sense. From the online examples and the books I've used it just seems there's so many (subtle) ways to do this incorrectly, I'm afraid to have the system not work as expected during actual use. Still, I have to learn at some point how to do things...

Comment: @musicamante Thanks. Maybe I should better have asked this question in the PyQT forums. Thank you for your remarks though. The `super().__init__()` was called but not copied when I tried to slim down my code for posting. Signals being declared at class level and not instance level is something I had not noticed before and I don't really understand why that happens. I'll try to figure that out. Thank you for your comments!

Comment: Going over both your comments makes me realize that I tried to think of the `LinkClient` as a module and using it as such. I now expect that I should rather see it as a "separate" part of code that runs on itself at the same time but can communicate using signals/slots nonetheless. I had methods that should be regularly called to keep the `LinkClient` running, but that functionality should be inside of the `LinkClient`, no? More "standalone running code" than "instance managed from the main window".

Comment: @DieterVansteenwegenON4DD Qt signals (as properties and slots) can only be declared at class level for QObject subclasses, they will never work properly if created in instances: signals will not be valid (trying to `emit()` them will result in an `AttributeError`), properties will not be *actual* Qt properties, and slots will not be treated as such (just like standard python functions). As said, I'm not familiar with RNS, so there may be different ways to achieve what you want; I'm not sure what you mean by that difference in your last sentence. Maybe you thought about an internal loop?

Comment: @DieterVansteenwegenON4DD If that's the case, it can be done, but would make intercommunication a bit difficult, especially if you want to use signals *from* the UI *to* the client: in that case, it's common to use a Thread.Queue and periodically check for further "events" in it. Still, the call back mechanism should be fine anyway, as long as the connections are done in the proper order (as ekhumoro said), but you need to be careful about the way communication happens and the life-span/thread-safety of the objects involved.

Comment: What I meant is that I started writing the `LinkClient` class as a module as I've always done, thinking that I could instantiate it and use its methods to "control" it from the main window. Now I think that assumption was wrong and I should have a method in the `LinkClient` class that takes care of everything that concerns the `LinkClient`. It should be happily doing its own thing, separately from the main window, while occasionally communicating with the main window (when it wants the `LinkClient` to send a message, ...) .

Comment: Not sure if that is properly explained, but there's a big difference in my head. I started writing a library thinking I could then create an instance and move that to a separate thread while using it as any other library. Now I'm thinking it should almost be able to run on its own, only occasionally communicating with the main window. Hope my explanation is a bit clear. If my current understanding is correct, a lot of do's/don'ts make more sense. I'll try it out and see where I get. In any case, thanks!

Comment: IMHO, there's no problem in calling methods from Qobjects that executes in another thread from the main window, given that you provide a way to synchronize access to data that is shared between both ends (variables, lists, files). The problem of communication between the main thread and spawned threads, is always the problem that: while one thread is writing data in a shared memory, another might be reading its incomplete value (reading literally trash or corrupted data). That's why you must use a mutex to guarantee some sort of synchronization. Qt5 provides the QMutex for that sort of needs.

Comment: Now of course, when creating a thread, and using the qobject.moveToThread(qthread) method, before calling qthread.start(), you must signalize to the QThread which method you want to run: in this case, `self.datalink_thread.started.connect(self.datalink.connect_to_server)` as @musicamante explained. But after that, any other method from that qobject can be called from the main thread, given you can guarantee you "won't shoot yourself on the feet" with the synchronization problem. That's one way to pass data from the main thread -> spawned thread.

Comment: "What I meant is that I started writing the LinkClient class as a module as I've always done, thinking that I could instantiate it and use its methods to "control" it from the main window." It looks like you wanted to create some sort of server, and when you call a method, LinkClient should execute something on the background. That's not how it works based on what you wrote. Once connect_to_server reaches the end of scope, the thread finishes executing. If you call a method from LinkClient, it executes that method in the current thread, not where the instance lives. So, that's not a server.

Comment: @CarlHR That depends on what the called method does, since directly calling a function always results in executing it in the calling thread (I know you know that, I'm just clarifying for the "safety of this thread"  ;-) ). That's why queues are common in Python/Qt, since they avoid any risk of blocking of the main thread (damn GIL!), based on the assumption that any given argument of a signal should be treated as non thread-safe. This is partly similar to what happens with queued signals in inter-thread comms. Btw, what do you mean by "`connect_to_server` [...] thread finishes executing"?

Comment: @musicamante Ok I get it, it's hard to explain it with a limit of characters. The QThread doesn't really quit/finish executing when `connect_to_server` reaches the end of the scope. In the background, afaik it starts its own QEventLoop (given that QThread.run was not overwritten by a subclass). So, from that point onwards, there's no way to communicate with the thread anymore in order to call RNS methods as the OP intended to. That's what I meant by "it finishes executing". There's no way to recover the thread other than calling quit/wait/start, provided that OP (dis)connects another method.

Comment: @CarlHR Ok, now I got what you meant, thanks. Yet, it's not impossible to start something "afterwards", at least by using signals and as long as methods are part of a QObject instance *moved* to a QThread, including a QThread "moved to itself"; that may seem awkward, but makes sense as soon as we remember that a QThread is a *manager* of the thread, not the thread itself, since the QThread *object* is originally part of the thread it was created into; if a connection is done to any of its methods then, those methods will be finally executed in the target thread that QThread actually manages.